# Java Abstract Class TransformerFactory can be instantiated?

Tags: java, abstract-class

As far as I know, a Java abstract class can not be instantiated. However, `TransformFactory` (abstract class) has this method:

`newInstance()`
Obtain a new instance of a `TransformerFactory.` And more details are given about JAXP and Properties in the documentation. Could anybody give a more clear explanation on this please?.

Comment: See java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()

Answer (score 1):

The abstract class isn't instantiated directly. A concrete subclass such as `SAXTransformerFactory` (which is partially made up of the abstract class) is instantiated, and that object is returned.

You can tell from the [method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()):

> This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the TransformerFactory implementation class to load...

Note the "implementation class"...

Answer (score 1):

> Could anybody give a more clear explanation on this please?.

It is OK.  The `newInstance()` method will return an instance of a *subclass* of `TransformerFactory`.

The operative word in the javadoc sentence that you quoted is the "a" word.

> Obtain a new instance of >>a<< `TransformerFactory`.

That little word "a" implies that it is not *the* `TransformerFactory` class (which is clearly impossible!) but some subclass.  The rest of the javadoc explains how `newInstance` decides which subclass to instantiate and return.

---

<sup>I accept that this use of "a" is rather subtle, and they *could* have made the description a bit more explicit.  However, I presume that the javadoc author preferred a less "wordy" description.</sup>